# Can winter lootboxes be opened after the winter event?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch players get 5 free winter lootboxes [if they log in between today and January 2nd](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5k4hi5/5_free_lootboxes_for_everyone_merry_christmas/dbldq0s/) (the end of the winter event). Can these still be opened once the event is over? From this I will extrapolate how other special event lootboxes work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, event lootboxes don't expire.

Comment: So, no? lol1234

Comment: You get confusing answers when you ask different questions in the title and body.

Comment: Not only do loot boxes not expire, but their contents are generated at the same time that the boxes are issued. This means that no matter how long you hold on to the boxes the items inside them are already predetermined and will simply be waiting, but they'll never change.